# How to fix the error: Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' after running yarn encore dev

Tags: symfony, webpack, puppeteer

I'm using Symfony/Webpack-Encore,and I'm trying to import puppeteer.

> webpack.config.js (notice the config.target = "node" at the end)

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

...

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.target = "node";
module.exports = config;
```

> extra.js (imported in app.js)

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker')

function getDom(url) {
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
    puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))
    puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 })
        await page.goto(url);
        const dom = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML)
        await browser.close()
        return dom;
    })
    return null;
}
```